# Can I reset Home button sensitivity?

Tags: iphone

I don't have a problem with the button itself, it seems that I need to push deeper to make it work.  I don't have to push harder... just deeper.

I remember someone talking about the "fact" you can reset sensitivity for the Home button of the iPhone.

Does this software sensitivity reset really exists ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, wrong. The home button is no sensor in the meaning of a pressure sensor.

For reference see [this](http://www.marco.org/2012/01/08/drang-home-button-calibration-voodoo).

Answer (score 1):

The home button is a mechanical button.  It can get gunged up over time like any other button, and one seemingly useful remedy for enabling freer movement like it was when you bought it is to apply a *tiny* amount of WD40 down the side of the button and rapidly press it lots whilst rotating the phone around on a level ish plane.

Comment: That sounds like a reaaaaaaaly bad idea. WD40 might isolate the contacts of the button. Beside, WD40 might dissolve the home button plastic...

Comment: Note: that should say "WD40", not "Hydrochloric Acid" ;)

Comment: You know Hydrochloric Acid is often stored in plastic containers? ;)

Comment: Smart-Alec retort ending in a wink face ;)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst reading this thread I literally put my mouth over the button and sucked and it's suddenly fine.

Answer (score -2):

I read it somewhere too, but I guess doing a soft reset will help in resetting home button sensitivity.

"To reset iPhone, press and hold the Sleep/Wake button and the Home button at the same time for at least 10 seconds, until the Apple logo appears."

Nothing is lost during a soft reset.